# Me falta acabar de perfilar este programa

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

```
def AddDictionary(s):
    i = 0
    result = {}
    for c in s:
        result[c] = i
        if result.has_key(c):
            i += 1
    return result

def theMostRepeated(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return "The list is empty"
    else: 
        keys = AddDictionary(s).keys() 
        mx = keys[0] 
        for key in keys: 
            if AddDictionary(s)[key] > AddDictionary(s)[mx]: #Al comparar las keys no se comparan los numeros sino los valores a los que se refieren
                mx = key 
        return mx
```

Este código lo que hace es contar las veces que sale un número en una lista. Si la lista está vacía pone el mensaje de "the list is empty" y lo que me falla es que no sé como aprovechando las funciones que he hecho puedo hacer que si dos números se repiten la misma cantidad de veces que devuelva el primero que salga en la lista.
Un ejemplo de la función seria este: print theMostRepeated([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de lo que preguntas, hay un error de diseño en tu código, y algunas ineficiencias.

## AddDictionary()

Empecemos por la función `AddDictionary()`. Se entiende que el objetivo de esta función es recibir una lista y construir un diccionario cuyas claves son los elementos de la lista y los valores el número de veces que aparece ese elemento en la lista ¿no?

Primero un detalle. Veo que usas `result.has_key(c)` para mirar si una clave está o no en un diccionario. Esta sintaxis es de Python 2, en Python 3 ha sido eliminada. Se recomienda que uses `c in result` para lograr el mismo objetivo, sintaxis que es válida en cualquier versión de Python.

Por otro lado creo que la función no hace lo que pretendías. Tomemos por caso la lista `[20,20,30,30]`. Si invocas tu función con esa lista, en lugar del resultado esperado `{20: 2, 30: 2}`, obtienes `{20: 1, 30: 3}`. El por qué se entiende si ejecutas mentalmente la función "paso a paso".

- Comienzas haciendo `i=0` y `result={}`
- En la primera iteración del bucle `c` vale 20, mientras que `i` vale 0. Haces por tanto `result[20]=0`, lo que ya está mal, pues deberías contar que el 2 ha salido una vez, pero asignas en cambio un 0.
- Miras si `20` está en el diccionario. ¡Pero siempre estará pues acabas de meterlo en la línea anterior! Este test por tanto es superfluo, y la línea siguiente `i+=1` se ejecutará siempre.
- En la siguiente iteración del bucle `c` de nuevo es `20`, por lo que asignas a `result[20]` el nuevo valor de `i` que es 1. Sigue estando mal. Y después incrementas `i`, que pasa a valer 2.
- Lo que ocurre a partir de ahora es peor todavía, pues viene un `30` y haces `result[30]=2`.
- Ya que según hemos visto la línea `i+=1` se ejecuta siempre, en el fondo `i` no cuenta cuántas veces ha aparecido cada número (un solo contador no podría hacer eso), sino cuántas veces hemos iterado en el bucle.
- En la iteración final se asigna `result[30]=3`

No puedes tener un solo contador. Necesitas uno para cada posible valor de la lista. Pero precisamente esos contadores son los que guardas en el diccionario. Por tanto la versión corregida de tu código sería:

```
def AddDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    for c in s:
      if c in result:   # Si ya había un contador para c, lo incrementamos
        result[c] += 1
      else:
        result[c] = 1   # Si no, lo creamos con valor 1
    return result
```

### theMostRepeated()

Entiendo que el cometido de esta función es devolver cuál es el elemento que más veces se ha repetido. Por tanto cuál es la clave del diccionario que tiene un valor mayor.

Tu implementación llama innecesariamente a `AddDictionary()` muchas veces. En realidad basta que la llames una vez y almacenes el resultado para después operar sobre ese resultado. Es decir, puedes hacer esto otro:

```
def theMostRepeated(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return "The list is empty"
    else: 
        result = AddDictionary(s)
        keys = list(result.keys())
        mx = keys[0]
        for key in keys: 
            if result[key] > result[mx]: #Al comparar las keys no se comparan los numeros sino los valores a los que se refieren
                mx = key 
        return mx
```

Por otro lado he hecho `list()` alrededor de `result.keys()` para que sea compatible con Python 3, pues en esta versión de Python `result.keys()` ya no es una lista, sino un generador.

## Tu pregunta

¿Cómo hacer que si hay elementos que se repiten el mismo número de veces el resultado sea el que primero aparezca en la lista?

Esto implicaría tener un diccionario que mantuviera el orden de inserción. Ya que los elementos se van insertando en el orden en que se encuentran en la lista, si tuviéamos un diccionario que preservara ese orden (es decir, que cuando haces `diccionario.keys()` te devuelva las claves en el mismo orden en que fueron insertadas) tu problema estaría resuelto, ya que el máximo con que te quedarías correspondería al primer valor aparecido.

Por desgracia en Python 2 los diccionarios no preservan el orden de inserción. Es decir, cuando obtienes `diccionario.keys()` las claves vienen en cualquier orden impredecible (incluso puede ser diferente cada vez que ejecutas el programa con los mismos datos). A partir de Python 3.7 el orden de inserción en los diccionarios se preserva, por lo que si ejecutas el código anterior con Python 3.7 ya funcionaría como esperas sin tener que  hacer nada.

Para versiones inferiores de python tenemos el tipo [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) disponible incluso para Python 2.

Usando este tipo, bastaría reescribir la función `AddDictionary()` de este modo:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def AddDictionary(s):
    result = OrderedDict()
    for c in s:
      if c in result:
        result[c] += 1
      else:
        result[c] = 1
    return result
```

Y ya funcionará como esperas:

```
>>> theMostRepeated([3,3,3,2,2,2])
3
```

### Otra forma

Sin necesidad de introducir `OrderedDict()` sino haciendo uso tan solo de los tipos que ya tenías en tu código, otra solución puede ser que en `theMostRepeated()` iteres por los elementos de la lista en lugar de hacerlo por las claves del diccionario.

Así:

```
def theMostRepeated(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return "The list is empty"
    else: 
        result = AddDictionary(s)
        mx = s[0]
        for dato in s: 
            if result[dato] > result[mx]:
                mx = dato 
        return mx
```

El código queda incluso más legible, pero esta versión es más ineficiente que la anterior, ya que el bucle debe iterar por más elementos (la lista tendrá en general más elementos que claves había en el diccionario, sobre todo si los datos se repiten muchas veces).